# Microsoft Teams - Reached Connector Limit Despite No Connectors

Tags: office365, ms-office, microsoft-teams, office365connectors

I am receiving the error "You have reached the limit for number of Connectors. Please remove some connectors before adding more." when I try to go to the Connector dashboard.

[image]

I have zero connectors in the account - anyone have an idea on how to resolve this issue?

For additional context, I am the admin at the company, and have tried with a different user as well who has full developer permissions for Teams. I am brand new to Teams as a developer so unsure of how to proceed.

Comment: We are able to repro that issue , We have raised bug for the same and concerned team is looking into it. We will inform you once we get any update.

Comment: Now it's working fine. Could you please try it once?